# Javascript date deserialization using jacking

Tags: javascript, json, date, jackson

The date I'm sending to my web service

```
2015-03-01
```

the information that is being deserialized in the web service

```
1425189600000
```

The data that the web service is getting doesn't even look like the information I sent, and I haven't found anything through my googling that would fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: that's a unix timestamp, probably in javascript-style milliseconds, e.g. # of seconds/milliseconds since Jan 1/1970. 1425189600 -> "Sun, 01 Mar 2015 00:00:00 -0600" you can feed either format directly to date, `x = new Date(142...)` and it'll work out ok.

Comment: Both _JavaScript (Date)_ and your server (e.g. php's `date`) will give you methods to get this into a human-readable format. The number you have is how the computer understands time.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, putting that into the new Date param fixed it